# insert 4 spaces after adding multiple lines from a text file

Tags: bash, sed, text-files, line, spaces

I want to add multiple lines after matching a pattern. So from

```
Pattern:
bla
```

to

```
Pattern:
    line1-from-file1
    line2-from-file1
bla
```

I ran something like this `sed '/Pattern/r file1' file2` but it gave:

```
Pattern:
line1-from-file1
line2-from-file1
bla
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^/    /' file1 | sed '/pattern/r /dev/stdin' file2
```

Pipe a sed amended file1 into a second invocation of sed matching `pattern` in file2.

The ameliorated file1 is presented as `/dev/stdin` and added to the second sed by  way of the `r` command.